# Unable to drag brush tool in Photoshop CS5 in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wine, photoshop

I was able to use Photoshop CS5 perfectly on Ubuntu 11.10. After upgraded to 12.04 
I've noticed that when I try to use brush tool in by dragging the left mouse button I cannot get continous effect on photos. It only effects the area I click with mouse.

[image]

In the screenshot all the time I was holding the left mouse button but it only affected the image once, creating dots instead of lines.

At first I thought its something with Wine. I reinstalled it then deleted Photoshop in my `ApplicationData` folder (Windows keeps user software options in this folder). None of these worked. I tried on my laptop and this strange problem exists there too.

Comment: I am having the same problem. I can't click and drag using the brush since I updated from Ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04. I can't remember if I was running Wine 1.4 in Ubuntu 11.10, or an older version of Wine. Have you tried running an older version of Wine or the development release, 1.5.5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the similar problem with wine 1.4 and all the older wine versions. Now i installed Photoshop in wine 1.2(!) and it works like a charm. View picture below.

What i did was the following:

1. First get photoshop.exe from your installation CD.
2. Then i installed it in Playonlinux. First i installed wine 1.2 in playonlinux. (Settings/Manage Wine Versions) Then i pressed install and in the popup menu press: Install a non listed program. Then go to the setup and install the photoshop.exe
3. Then it run's like a charm.

Proof of my working brushes:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/xx5qj.jpg]

I haven't tested everything, but i tested most things and they all seem to work.

Greets

Comment: I'm not able to find Photoshop on the install menu within PlayOnLinux.  Is it no longer supported?

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem too before I updated to Wine 1.5. Now that I updated it, it still sometimes makes dots, but works more often. Here is how I updated to Wine 1.5 (unreleased version):

1. In your **Software Center** go to: **EDIT > Software Sources**
2. Once you're there open the **Other Software** tab and click "Add..." (but not "Add Volume...")
3. Paste this in:  `ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa`
4. Now open the **Terminal** and `sudo apt-get update` > `sudo apt-get install wine1.5`
5. Restart your computer *(may not be necessary, but just in case)* and run **Photoshop**

As I said, this isn't a total cure! Sometimes you'll still get dots instead of lines
but it worked for me, 6-7 times out of 10.
Also, Wine is constantly under development thus I'm sure
most problems will be solved within this month.

It's been a couple of days now and the problem seems to be gone.
I still can't use the Type tool though.

Answer (score 2):

I'm Running CS6 in 12.10, using a wacom tablet

After trying a few things I found out that the bug is only (nearly) not present with the tablet if you set the tablet configuration to "absolute" in System Settings. With "relative" it's just like using a mouse.

A bugfix seems to exist, but unfortunately still hasn't been implemented in the current wine version (1.5.20)
http://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=29871

Answer (score 2):

Ok guys its my first post for wine, and I'm french so, don't be to hard on me.

I tried the patch cause I had the same problem as you guys, and I worked it out!!!

I'm on Ubuntu 13.04, and I had wine 1.6

So I did a manual compilation of wine,

Started by downloading the 1.7 version [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wine/files/Source/)

Then extracted wine in my home folder, and manually edited the file `wine-1.7.0/dlls/user32/input.c` as shown in the patch (much easier than really patching I think).

Then I `apt-get` installed all these dependencies because `sudo apt-get build-dep wine` didnt work for me:

```
autotools-dev
bison
debhelper (>= 9)
docbook-to-man
docbook-utils
docbook-xsl
flex
fontforge
gcc-4.5
gettext
libasound2-dev
libcapi20-dev
libcups2-dev
libdbus-1-dev
libfontconfig1-dev
libfreetype6-dev
libgif-dev
libgl1-mesa-dev
libglu1-mesa-dev
libgnutls-dev
libgphoto2-2-dev
libgsm1-dev
libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev
libgstreamer0.10-dev
libjpeg-dev
liblcms1-dev
libldap2-dev
libmpg123-dev
libncurses5-dev
libopenal-dev
libpng12-dev
libsane-dev
libssl-dev
libtiff-dev
libv4l-dev
libx11-dev
libxcomposite-dev
libxcursor-dev
libxext-dev
libxi-dev
libxinerama-dev
libxml2-dev
libxrandr-dev
libxrender-dev
libxslt1-dev
libxt-dev
libxxf86vm-dev
linux-kernel-headers
opencl-headers
oss4-dev
prelink
unixodbc-dev
x11proto-xinerama-dev
```

Finally I did the compilation:

```
./configure && make
```

And woohoo!

```
./wine ~/photoshop.exe
```

This way i suppose you can get rid of this bug in any version of wine.

Cheers!

Comment: everything works well on wine-1.7.41, After commenting out an `if` statement about line 380 in mentioned file.  So, Merci encore Mr, French.

Comment: This is the patch in question: https://github.com/PlayOnLinux/wine-patches/blob/master/custom/photoshop-cs5/photoshop-brushes.patch

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Photoshop CS6 with wine 1.5. I had the same symptons, but after the upgrade to wine 1.5 it got indeed much better.

Using a Wacom tablet for drawing with brushes reduces the problem drastically.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on Ubuntu 15.10 with Photoshop CC 2014. One [article](http://www.yaseendadabhay.com/linux/how-to-install-photoshop-cc-in-linux/) suggested using `1.7.41-PhotoshopBrushes` but that didn't seem to work, I eventually found [another article](http://www.bendangelo.me/install/2014/10/29/installing-photoshop-cs6-on-ubuntu.html) that suggests using `1.7.20-PhotoshopBrushes` which works perfectly!

From the second tutorial:

- Go back to the main PlayOnLinux window, select the Photoshop program and then click on **Configure**.
- Click on the **+** to install a new version of Wine, then install the `1.7.20-PhotoshopBrushes` Wine version. Then go back and select it from the dropdown.